# Fefferman metric and Einstein metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

From Lee's paper **The Fefferman Metric and Pseudo hermitian Invariants**,  corresponding to any 3 dimensional strictly pseudo convex CR structure, there is a conformal class of  Lorentzian metrics which are not Einstein. Is there any condition on the CR structure under which a representative of the conformal class is Einstein? Or in another words, when is a Fefferman metric Einstein?

Comment: Lee said himself in his paper that Fefferman metric is never  Einstein, but g Fefferman conformal class can have Einstein metric in local sense

Comment: You may see this paper F. Leitner: On transversally symmetric pseudo-Einstein and Fefferman-Einstein spaces,
Math. Z. 256 (2007), no. 2, 443–459.

Comment: When $(M,θ,J)$ is  transversally symmetric pseudo-Einstein, the conformal class of $f_θ$  contain an Einstein metric

Comment: @Hassan Jolany, How can I see that g Fefferman conformal class can have Einstein metric in local sense ?

Comment: For $3$-dimensional CR-structures having an Einstein representative even locally forces local equivalence to the standard CR $3$-sphere. See Prop. 3 of J. Lewandowski, *On the Fefferman Class of Metrics Associated with a Three-Dimensional CR Space* Letters Math. Phys. **15** (1988), 129--135.